# Route traffic to host machine when building a docker container

Tags: python, docker, pip

An docker image I'm building pulls a lot of python packages via pip.

```
RUN pip install -r lots-of-packages.txt
```

My host machine is running a PyPi package mirror and cache so that these packages can be downloaded quickly.

The `pip install` command allows users to specify the location for the package index via argument `--index-url`:

```
RUN pip install --index-url http://localhost:3141/root/pypi/ -r lots-of-packages.txt
```

However, during `docker build` the host `localhost` refers to the docker container itself, not my host machine that is serving the cache.

How can I access network resources on the host machine when building a docker container via `docker build`?

`docker build --add-host <host>:<ip>` seems like it would allow me to set up a hostname for an IP, but is there a valid IP to address the host during the build?

Comment: → `RUN pip install -r lots-of-packages.txt`

Comment: Thanks @KlausD. I have fixed that typo.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by specifying the network mode when building:

```
docker build --network host ...
```

Comment: `"--network" requires API version 1.25, but the Docker daemon API version is 1.23` **sigh**, I think I am on the latest release for macOS. I may have to find some way to install the pre-release.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest would be to check ip of docker0 bridge (by using `ip a` command for example) and use host ip on that bridge instead of localhost. So assuming you run Linux and docker0 ip is 172.17.0.1 your command will look like this:

`RUN pip install --index-url http://172.17.0.1:3141/root/pypi/ lots-of-packages.txt`

If you are running on Windows or Mac then probably some port forwarding will be involved.

Comment: I *am* on Mac and there is no `docker0` device. Let me see if I can figure out how to set that up.

Comment: AFAIK docker on Mac uses some kind of VM to have Linux kernel. So if your proxy runs on host and not inside of this VM you will need to forward the port from host to VM. I run Linux and won't be able to help with that but search term I would use is: "docker mac forward port from host"